# SQLite: How to post default column value instead of NULL

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm learning Python and working on a simple webapp to handle some admin tasks. I have a scenario where a user fills out a form whith two text fields and a checkbox, the checkbox serving as a y/n flag. Checked = y and unchecked = n.

From here, I need to post 'y' or 'n' to the database. The default value of this column is 'n' (in the SQLite schema: `booleancolumn TEXT DEFAULT n`)

```
formlist=[request.form('textfield1'), request.form('textfield2'), request.form('booleanfield')]

if request.form('booleanfield') == None:
    formlist[2] = 'n'

db.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES(?, ?, ?)', tuple)
```

Problem is, this code just posts NULL into the boolean column if the checkbox is unchecked.

So now I handle it with a 2-liner `if` statement which manually adds 'n' to the form variable if it comes in empty (unchecked) from the user.

I dont't like this, and I expect SQLite to add the default value by default. Is there a way to do this?

Ps: this is a very simple, very static scenario so I'd like to avoid creating the SQL insert statement dynamically with a different `if` statement.

Comment: Before anything else, `tuple` is a terrible name for a variable. You're trampling over a builtin name

Comment: Secondly, you need to show how `booleanfield` is defined. If you do something like `req = request.form.to_dict()` then you could do `booleanfield = req.get('booleanfield', 0)` and then you have something other than `None`. But then there are questions about the schema itself

Comment: Please [edit] your question. If you post in comments it will be illegible

Comment: Ok, then I've answered your question. Just do `req = request.form.to_dict()`, which just gives you a bog-standard python dictionary, and then you can use [.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405/4799172) with a default of `0` or `False` to avoid the `NULL` entry

Comment: Thanks, will check. Just for the sake of me understand the sql side of it: is there no way to tell SQLite to 'ignore' NULL and fall back to the default value? Maybe only for a specific table/column?

Comment: Not that I know of on this basis, though potentially. `alembic` could set a default but it's not worth setting that up _just_ for something like this. _You_ can control the default at the point of insertion by just adding the value to the query